# Random True or false using math.random

Tags: java, math, random, boolean

How to return true or false, only using Math.random(), without creating a new method or using java.util.random?

Comment: `Math.random() > 0.5`

Comment: Research what the range of `Math.random()` is, and determine how you can split that range in half and assign one half `true` and the other half `false`.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Do you have an output example or something?

Comment: To use `Math.random()` to get a boolean value.

Comment: You gotta print "Random Boolean=" and the answer must be true or false. I can only use Math.random() and the simple answer as possible(so I don't want to use if() or anything more complex than that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Math.random() returns a double between zero and one, inclusive.

So,

```
boolean value;

if(Math.random() > 0.5) value = true;
else value = false;
```

Also, `Random.nextBoolean()`

Comment: It's not just `0` or `1`, it's ["a `double` value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to `0.0` and less than `1.0`."](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#random()).

Comment: Is it possible to do it without using if()? And is 50% chance for true and false?

Comment: Random.nextBoolean(), and yes "java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBoolean();"

Comment: but isn't Random.nextBoolean() from java.util.Random?

Comment: Whoops. I meant that java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBoolean(); works as well.

Comment: Is my answer correct? If no, please explain what you'd like me to add.

Comment: I forgot to tell to not use if's, but I think there is no simple way to do this without using if or the ternary operator(for my level of java). So yes, I think your answer is correct, I just thought that maybe could exist any simple way to do it.

Comment: Note: `random()` is about 48x more expensive than `nextBoolean()`